# Can super user write into read-only files?

Tags: files, permissions, root

I've stumbled upon surprising (for me) permission behavior on FreeBSD. Let's say I'm operating as **non-root** user. I create a file, set its permission on read-only and then try to write into it:

```
$ touch f
$ chmod 400 f
$ ls -l f
-r--------  1 user  wheel  f
$ echo a >> t
t: Permission denied.
```

So far so good. Now I do the same as root and it writes into the file:

```
# ls -l f2
-r--------  1 root  wheel  f2
# echo a >> f2
# echo $?
0
```

Is it a bug or intended behavior? Can I safely assume that this would work so on any Unix & Linux?

Comment: Any user with `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` can do this. On nearly all Linux systems this means root can do this so it's intentional. Can't speak for the FreeBSD part but I'd imagine they have a similar setup.

Comment: The reason root needs to ALWAYS be able to write to a file is because on traditional unix filesystems (ext4, zfs etc.) file permissions are part of the file. So if root cannot write to a file then NOBODY can make read-only file writable again because `chmod` cannot write to the file.

Comment: @slebetman You don't need to have write access to a file to update the permissions. Just try `touch somefile; chmod 0000 somefile; chmod 0644 somefile` as a normal user.

Comment: @immibis: That you own. Root needs to be able to change permissions on files that it doesn't own

Comment: @slebetman Yeah... but you were talking about changing permissions on files you can't write to, not about changing permissions on file you don't own.

Comment: @slebetman note that modifying the file data (writing to it) is completely different operation (syscall) from changing its metadata (updating owner, group, permissions etc.) You'll also note that `stat(2)` thus returns different fields `mtime` (modified time) and `ctime` (changed time) representing when each of the above actions last happened. So `chmod` doesn't "write to the file" (ie. it only changes inode metadata, not its data - it is important difference to make)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's normal for `root` to be able to override permissions in this manner.

Another example is `root` being able to read a file with no read access:

```
$ echo hello > tst
$ chmod 0 tst
$ ls -l tst
---------- 1 sweh sweh 6 Aug 16 15:46 tst
$ cat tst
cat: tst: Permission denied
$ sudo cat tst
hello
```

Some systems have the concept of *immutable* files.  eg on FreeBSD:

```
# ls -l tst
-rw-r--r--  1 sweh  sweh  6 Aug 16 15:50 tst
# chflags simmutable tst
# echo there >> tst
tst: Operation not permitted.
```

Now even `root` can't write to the file.  But, of course, `root` can *remove* the flag:

```
# chflags nosimmutable tst
# echo there >> tst
# cat tst
hello
there
```

With FreeBSD you can go a step further and set a kernel flag to prevent `root` from removing the flag:

```
# chflags simmutable tst
# sysctl kern.securelevel=1
kern.securelevel: -1 -> 1
# chflags nosimmutable tst
chflags: tst: Operation not permitted
```

Now no one, not even `root` can change this file.

(The system needs rebooting to reduce the securelevel).

Comment: How is requiring reboot an effective security measure? Also, if root is root and can do anything, why even bother trying to prevent root from doing what root wants?

Comment: On a secure system, root is _not_ God-like.  FreeBSD securelevel is a small attempt to make root less God like.  Securelevel can be set to default to 1 in system config so it stays active even after a reboot.  So then it'd need console access and single user mode and that's very tamper evident.  There's a whole essay around Unix security that's far too much for a SE comment field, but we're trying to move on from a 'root has all access' model into something more nuanced.  We try to enforce where possible (eg securelevel) and detect where not (reboot evidence, audit trails).

Comment: FWIW, in Linux `chattr +i tst` sets _immutable_ attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is very normal. root has no limits on read/write (with very little exception), because he is the root.